# How to post a SOAP request using Swagger in WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure the try-it swagger ui utility with a SOAP web service. I tried to set the SOAPAction header property and as soon as I set it it won't work.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you had created an API from your SOAPService and trying to invoke it using swagger.

Change the swagger path with SOAPAction. Then invoke the method by sending the SOAP body in the Payload. For example if your SOAPAction is **AddStudent**,

```
        "path": "/studentapi/1.0/AddStudent",
        "description": "",
        "operations": [
            {
                "httpMethod": "POST",
                "summary": "",
                "nickname": "",
                "parameters": [
                         "name": "Payload",
                        "description": "Request Payload",
                        "paramType": "body",
                        "required": false,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "dataType": "String"
                    }
```

[image]

Please refer the below post, which explains how to send additional headers in swagger requests.

http://blog.lakmali.com/2013/10/how-to-add-additional-headers-to-wso2.html

Comment: Thanks Lakmali, I tried that and it didn't work? I used fiddler to capture the request and it is still not adding the soapaction header parameter

Comment: Hi Aws, I 've updated the abive answer pointing toa blog post which shows how to add additional headers to swagger requests in wso2 api manager